# Error when verifying signature: SigningCertificate property contains one or more certificates that are not part of the certification path

Tags: java, xades4j

I'm using xades4j and I'm getting this exception when trying to verify signature:

```
xades4j.verification.SigningCertificateCertsNotInCertPathException: Verification failed for property 'SigningCertificate': SigningCertificate property contains one or more certificates that are not part of the certification path.
```

Here is my code to sign:

```
public File sign(final X509Certificate x509, final PrivateKey priv, final Element elemToSign, final Document doc, final String fileName, final com.softexpert.crypto.document.Document document, List<X509Certificate> chain) throws Exception {
    final KeyingDataProvider kp = new SEDirectKeyingDataProvider(x509, priv, chain);
    XadesSigningProfile profile = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp);
    final SESignaturePropertiesProvider propProv = this.getPropertiesProvider(document);

    profile = profile.withSignaturePropertiesProvider(propProv);
    profile = profile.withAlgorithmsProvider(AlgorithmsProvider.class);
    profile = profile.withTimeStampTokenProvider(TimeStampTokenProvider.class);

    final SignerBES signer = (SignerBES) profile.newSigner();
    final IndividualDataObjsTimeStampProperty dataObjsTimeStamp = new IndividualDataObjsTimeStampProperty();
    final DataObjectDesc obj = new EnvelopedXmlObject(elemToSign.getFirstChild()).withDataObjectTimeStamp(dataObjsTimeStamp);

    AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty commitment = null;
    if (document.isProofOfOrigin() != null && document.isProofOfOrigin()) {
        commitment = AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty.proofOfOrigin();
    } else {
        commitment = AllDataObjsCommitmentTypeProperty.proofOfReceipt();
    }

    SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects(obj).withCommitmentType(commitment);
    dataObjs = dataObjs.withDataObjectsTimeStamp();

    signer.sign(dataObjs, elemToSign);
    return this.outputDocument(doc, fileName);
}

private SESignaturePropertiesProvider getPropertiesProvider(com.softexpert.crypto.document.Document document) {
    SESignaturePropertiesProvider propertiesProvider = new SESignaturePropertiesProvider();

    if (document.getRole() != null) {
        final SignerRoleProperty signerRole = new SignerRoleProperty().withClaimedRole(document.getRole());
        propertiesProvider.setSignerRole(signerRole);
    }
    final SigningTimeProperty signingTime = new SigningTimeProperty();
    propertiesProvider.setSigningTime(signingTime);

    if (document.getLocalityName() != null && document.getCountry() != null) {
        final SignatureProductionPlaceProperty signatureProductionPlaceProperty = new SignatureProductionPlaceProperty(document.getLocalityName(), document.getCountry());
        propertiesProvider.setSignatureProductionPlaceProperty(signatureProductionPlaceProperty);
    }

    return propertiesProvider;
}

private File outputDocument(final Document doc, String fileName) throws Exception {
    if (!fileName.endsWith(".dsg")) {
        fileName += ".dsg";
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    File f = null;
    try {
        final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        f = new File(fileName);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            new File(f.getParent()).mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();
        }
        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        tf.newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
    } finally {
        if(out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    return f;
}
```

And here is my code to verify:

```
try {
    final org.w3c.dom.Document doc = this.getDomDocument();
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    // Find Signature element
    final NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
    final CertStore crls = ... // get CRLS
    final CertStore certs = ... // get intermediate certs                
    final KeyStore ks = ... // get KS from Windows-ROOT
    final PKIXCertificateValidationProvider cvp = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false, certs, crls);
    final XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(cvp);
    p.withTimeStampTokenVerifier(SETimeStampTokenProvider.class);
    final Element signatureElemntNode = (Element) nl.item(0);
    final XadesVerifier verifier = p.newVerifier();
    XAdESVerificationResult verificationResult = verifier.verify(signatureElemntNode, null); // exception is thrown here
}
```

I've searched for this error but couldn't find anything to help me. How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [lgoncalve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40876272/2836945), I've changed my code a little bit:

**Signing**: Instead of signing with the whole chain of certificates, I used only the signing certificate, so that `SEDirectKeyingDataProvider.getSigningCertificateChain()` returns only the signing cert). With this approach, my xml now has only one property `<SigningCertificate>` and no more the whole chain.

**Verifying**: Using the approach I've commented above, I had a problem when verifying certs: in my xml, only the signing certificate was being referenced in property `<ds:X509Certificate>`, so that I could not verify the whole chain. To solve it, I had to use this code **after** calling `XAdESVerificationResult result = verifier.verify(signatureElemntNode, null);`:

```
for(X509Certificate cert : chain) {         
   result.getSignature().addKeyInfo(cert);
}
```

Using this code, each cert of the chain is referenced by a property `<ds:X509Certificate>` and I can obtain the whole chain to verify if it is trustworthy or not.

Answer (score 1):

As the error messages states, your `SigningCertificate` property probably has certificates that are not part of the certificate chain. This rule is defined on the XAdES spec.

Regarding the signing operation:

- What certificates are you returning from the `getSigningCertificateChain` method of your custom `SEDirectKeyingDataProvider`?
- What are the certificate elements on the final XML of the `SigningCertificate` property?

The returned certificates should all be part of the chain for the singing certificate, but you don't need to return the full chain. You can even return a list that only contains the signing certificate, as long as you make all the intermediate certificates available to the validation (which you seem to be doing). If you do this, the validation for the `SigningCertificate` property should pass.

Comment: `getSigningCertificateChain` returns: CN=AC CAIXA v2, OU=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
CN=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
CN=AC CAIXA PF v2, OU=Caixa Economica Federal, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR
CN=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR

And `SigningCertificate` property shows those 4 certificates.. I cannot paste it becase of characters limit

Comment: `certs` (the variable that contains intermediate certificates), shows those 4 certificates also. I noticed that C=BR CN=Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v2, OU=Instituto Nacional de Tecnologia da Informacao - ITI, O=ICP-Brasil, C=BR appears twice. You think that this may be a problem?

Comment: You seem to have a repeated certificate. The verification will fail because of that ([see here](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/main/java/xades4j/verification/SigningCertificateVerifier.java#L112)). Note that returning duplicates on `getSigningCertificateChain` is not correct (and the library doens't check that). Maybe verification could be a bit smarter, but I think having duplicates is not very correct. Hope this helps